# Any body deployed GrayLog successfully?

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails, graylog

We are looking for a open source logging system and found [Graylog2](http://graylog2.org) as one of the best one. Anybody having some experience in setting up?

Any blog post you got while installing. I have few but still afraid to mess up the things.

PS: Suggesions for other better solutions are most welcome.

Comment: We've been using Graylog in production for about 3 months now. It took about a day to roll it out to a production-ready server, so I would not say it is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Their wiki pretty much covers it.

The server

https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server/wiki/Installing

The web frontend

https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-web-interface/wiki/Installing-the-web-interface-on-Debian-5.0

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an idea for what it's like to have your own production Graylog2 instance, try spinning up this Vagrant project:
https://github.com/mariussturm/vagrant_graylog2

It will boot an Ubuntu VM and install Graylog2 using instructions sent to Opsocde Chef, a systems integration tool.

Answer (score 0):

I succesfully deployed graylog2 on an ArchLinux box.
I also created packages on AUR (an untrusted repository of user-provided packages, similar to ubuntu's PPAs):

- https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=49133
- https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=49135

Comment: I am using Ubuntu :(

Comment: There are also Ubuntu/Debian packages for graylog2. See https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-web-interface/wiki/HOWTO:-Installing-Graylog2-%28server-and-web%29-via-Ubuntu-Lucid-Packages/